# How to select by class or id using selenium Webdriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

i'm using Java/Selenium-webdriver/Eclipse

i want to click on an element which is in a menu of a webapp.
So i have to click on Menu and it shows a list and then i clik on an item.

i try to select the item "Chaine" with linkText and sometimes it's working
When i select with xpath it's working but i think it's not safe.
So i want to select by id or class.

How can i select "Chaine" by Id or class.
Or what is the best way to select this item.

THank you

So the html code is here:

```
<ul class="list">
    <li class="component-panel-item" data-component="bar-graph">
        <a>
          Bar graph
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="component-panel-item" data-component="line-graph-ch">
        <a>
            Chaine
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="component-panel-item" data-component="line-graph-en">
        <a>
            En Graph
        </a>
    </li>
```

Comment: What's wrong with XPath?

Answer (score 0):

You can try out below code.

```
IWebElement ul = ie.FindElement(By.ClassName("list"));
ul.Click();
foreach (IWebElement li in ul.FindElements(By.ClassName("component-panel-item")))
{
   if (li.Text.Equals("Chaine"))
   {
       li.Click();
   }
}
```